# Scroll view and View goes up when key board appears iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am developing one iPad application using story board .For my iPad application, I need to display 4 `UICollectionView` in one screen.but I don't have enough space in the screen for displaying all 4 `UICollectionView`, so I need to add one scroll view to my view controller and display the CollectionViews inside the scrollview.Each cell in the collectionView, all collection views have one textfield.But if the key board appears, then the 3rd CollectionView and 4th CollectionView get hid behind the keyboard. so what I need to do is to get the CollectionViews up and my views inside the scroll view when the key board appears. Need guidance on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Add observers for keyboard visible and hide notifications.And adjust the frame of scrollview Accordingly

Comment: @Suhail I am new in ios. Would you please explain step by step as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardIsShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardIsShown:(NSNotification*)notification
{
         NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    //Adjust your scrollview frame by reducing the height by keyboardSize.Height

}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     // Set the scrollview frame back to normal.
}
```

Comment: call registerForKeyboardNotifications in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: thank you for your help.But first i need to set one scroll view.But Scroll view is not working .Would please help me to set that also in story board

Comment: Simply drag and drop and set the delegate and create the IBoutlet, thats enf

Comment: I missed to set delegate.Now set delegate also.But how to set height of the scrollview directly set in size inspector?

Comment: thats in size inspector , next to attribute inspector

Comment: I did following steps.1)drag and drop scroll view in to my parent view.2)Set delegate for scroll view. 3) create outlet for scroll view.  4)set scroll view size as 1000 in size inspector. but the scroll is not appear i need to set anything more? like need to set parent view size also 1000px in size inspector?

Comment: scroolview is not appearing or scrolling is not appeared?

Comment: set the size of scrollview same as ur self.view(same size).And set the content size as ur 4th collection view's origin.y + 4th collectionView.height + 20.Then u can get the scrolling also.

Comment: scrolling is not appearing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56511/discussion-between-suhail-and-user3762713).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of keyboard notifications. An example could be like this:

In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil]; //This gets triggered when the keyboard comes up. 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil]; // This gets triggered when the keyboard goes down.
```

And somewhere in your code, you can implement methods to handle the scrollView like this:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

// Code to move the UIScrollView up when the keyboard comes up

}



-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

// Code to move the UIScrollView down when the keyboard goes down. 

}
```

**Edit:**

This is clearly explained in this  [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard--mobile-6103)

Comment: thank you for your help.But first i need to set one scroll view.But Scroll view is not working .Would please help me to set that also  in story board